# How to save store after click checkcolumn?

Tags: extjs

I use checkcolumn in my grid. I want to save store AFTER click checkcolumn ( in my store autosave=false ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After click checkcolumn 'click' event happend. add listener to this event, if status of checkcolumn is correct (I assume 'on') fireEvent 'time_to_save_store', setup handler to this event in grid which will save your store....